# Regex to match character if not between digits

Tags: regex, language-agnostic, regex-lookarounds

I need to match a character to split a big string, let's say `-`, but not if it's between two digits

In `a-b` it should match `-`

In `a-4` it should match `-`

In `3-a` it should match `-`

In `3-4` it should not match

I've tried negative lookahead and lookbehind, but I've only been able to come up with this `(?<=\D)-(?=\D)|(?<=\d)-(?=\D)|(?<=\D)-(?=\d)`

Is there a simpler way to specify this pattern?

Edit: using regex conditionals I think I can use `(?(?<=\D)-|-(?=\D))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is to use an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) to match a `-` when on the left is not a digit or match a `-` when on the right is not a digit:

```
(?<!\d)-|-(?!\d)
```

- `(?<!\d)-` Negative lookbehind, assert what is on the left is not a digit and match -
- `|` or
- `-(?!\d)` Match `-` and assert what is on the right is not a digit using a negative lookahead

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/l8W4R8/1)

Answer (score 2):

The following will work for this scenario. Be sure that your Regex flavor of choice has conditionals, otherwise this will not work:

```
-(?(?=\d)(?<=\D-))

-         // match a dash
(?        // If
   (?=\d) // the next character is a digit
   (?<=   // then start a lookbehind (assert preceding characters are)
      \D- // a non-digit then the dash we matched
   )      // end lookbehind
)         // end conditional
```

With nothing as the substitution, as the dash is the only character captured.

Comment: I didn't know about conditionals, thank you! I think I just need `(?(?<=\D)-|-(?=\D))`, as I explicitly need to only match the character, not the surrounding digits

Comment: I added an edit with a quicker, simpler regex for this. It will only match the `-`

Comment: The simpler version is exactly what I was looking for, thanks again! Maybe it should replace the rest of the answer

Comment: Updated the answer to only have the new one, now that you've confirmed it was what you were looking for! Glad I could help!